# Solve differential ecuation $-\cosh^{2}(v)(u')^{2}+(v')^{2}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I'm studying differential geometry, my main reference is do Carmo and right now I'm stuck with this problem: I want to find the asymptotic curves of $x^{2}+y^{2}−z^{2}=1$. First, I considered the parametrization $$X(u,v)=(\cosh(v) \cos(u),\cosh(v) \sin(u),\sinh(v)),\, u \in (0,2 \pi),\, v>0$$ of this surface.

$$
X_{u}=(-\sin(u) \cosh(v), \cos(u) \cosh(v),0), 
$$
$$
X_{v}=(\cos(u) \sinh(v), \sinh(v) \sin(u), \cosh(v)),
$$
$$
N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cosh(2v)}}(\cos(u) \cosh(v), \sin(u) \cosh(v), -\sinh(v)),
$$
$$
X_{uu}=(-\cos(u) \cosh(v), -\sin(u) \cosh(v),0),
$$
$$
X_{uv}=(-\sin(u) \sinh(v), \cos(u) \sinh(v),0),
$$
$$
X_{vv}=(\cosh(v) \cos(u), cosh(v) \sin(u), \sinh(v)).
$$

Thus, the second fundamental form is given by $e=\frac{-\cosh^{2}(v)}{\sqrt{\cosh(2v)}}$, $f=0$, $g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cosh(2v)}}$.

Now, let $\alpha (t)=X(u(t),v(t))$ be a curve on the one-sheeted hyperboloid. It's well known that the curve $\alpha (t)$ is asymptotic if and only if $e(u′)^{2}+2fu′v′+g(v′)^{2}=0$. In this case, we have 
$-\cosh^{2}(v)(u')^{2}+(v')^{2}=0$. How can I solve this differential ecuation? After do it, I think [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299688/asymptotic-curves-of-one-sheet-hyperboloid) I can find out a way to continue. You will also see that the differential equation to give at the link is $-\cosh(v)(u')^{2}+(v')^{2}=0$, is anyone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using chain rule you have $\frac{dv}{du}=\sqrt{\cosh v}$, you can then integrate and find v in terms of u.

Comment: But $u$ and $v$ depends on $t$. So knowing this, can I derivate $v(t)$ respect to $u(t)$?

Comment: When $u'(t) \neq 0$ at some $t$, when $u$ is locally invertible. So $v(t) = v(t(u))$ is a function of $u$.